# Concatenating specific string to a range of values but getting "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length" error

Tags: r

I have a dataframe table **clutch_coupons** with columns:

Head.of.household.id
Balance.of.Points
Coupon_value
Coupon.URL

A coupon is assigned to a user with a specific point value. I was able to accomplish that with this code:

```
clutch_coupons$coupon_value[clutch_coupons$Balance.of.Points<= 499] <- 1.0
clutch_coupons$coupon_value[clutch_coupons$Balance.of.Points>= 1000 & clutch_coupons$Balance.of.Points< 1500] <- 8.50
clutch_coupons$coupon_value[clutch_coupons$Balance.of.Points >= 1500 & clutch_coupons$Balance.of.Points< 2000] <- 12.00
clutch_coupons$coupon_value[clutch_coupons$Balance.of.Points.null >= 2000 & clutch_coupons$Balance.of.Points< 2500] <- 15.00
clutch_coupons$coupon_value[clutch_coupons$Balance.of.Points>= 2500 & clutch_coupons$Balance.of.Points < 3100] <- 20.00
```

I also need to assign a coupon url that is unique to each of the 6 coupons by concatenating the url string with Head.of.household.id

For example:
Balance.of.Points < 499 gets a $1 coupon 
url = [https://offer.com/1dollar?[Head.of.household.id]](https://offer.com/1dollar?%5BHead.of.household.id%5D)
The final product should look like https://offer.com/1dollar?123456

Balance.of.Points >= 500 and <1000 gets a $8.5 coupon 
url = [https://offer.com/850dollar?[Head.of.household.id]](https://offer.com/850dollar?%5BHead.of.household.id%5D)
The final product should look like https://offer.com/850dollar?7890

and so on

I tried this code

```
clutch_coupons$Coupon.URL[clutch_coupons$Balance.of.Points >= 500 & clutch_coupons$Balance.of.Points.null < 1000] <- paste0("https://offer.com/850dollar?",clutch_coupons$Head.of.household.id)
```

but the results weren't right and I got the message

Warning message:
In clutch_coupons$Coupon.URL[clutch_coupons$Balance.of.Points.null >=  :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

I also tried an ifelse

```
clutch_coupons$Coupon.URL <- ifelse(is.na(clutch_coupons$Coupon.URL) & clutch_coupons$Balance.of.Points >= 500 & clutch_coupons$Balance.of.Points < 1000, paste0("https://offer.com/850dollar?",clutch_coupons$Head.of.household.id), NA)
```

But since the else statement is NA, it was just rewriting the previous statement results to NA
How do I update the ifelse statement so that I can run through the 6 iterations of coupon urls?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you're amenable to a `dplyr` approach, this would be easier to maintain as a non-equi join to a lookup table. Then the values can live in a table instead of custom code prone to typos (I think?) like `clutch_coupons$coupon_value[clutch_coupons$Balance.of.Points.null`.

```
lookup <- data.frame(coupon_value = c(1, 0, 8.5, 12, 15, 20, 0), 
                     min_points = c(0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3100))

library(dplyr)
clutch_coupons %>% 
  left_join(lookup, join_by(closest(Balance.of.Points >= min_points)))
```